# How to get the input of a selectpickers liveSearch

Tags: javascript, html, input, bootstrap-selectpicker, livesearch

I have a select with 3 options and a liveSearch. If the users type an input in the liveSearch-box which doesn't exist as an option, I get the result "No results matched xy". But I want to know, what the user wrote. How do I get his input?

```
<body class="inventorypage" onload="selectM()">
.....
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="select_box">
                <select class="select4 col-md-12" single title="Auswählen" id="searchInput">
                    <option>Search1</option>
                    <option>Search2</option>                                                                                
                    <option>Search3</option>
                </select>                                                                                                                                                               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <button type="button" onclick="searchM()" class="btn3 mt-2 mb-3">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div>                           
            <p id='output'></p>
        </div>      
    </div>  
</form>
```

```
function selectM(){
    var eingabe = document.getElementById('searchInput');   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.select4').selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true
            //,noneResultsText: 'I found no results'
         });
    })
}

function searchM(){
    //console.log("users input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The select picker creates a search input box with the class name bs-searchbox. You can get the value by following the code.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select4 .bs-searchbox input', function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
```

Comment: I want only to get the value, if there is no other option found (which means if I get the output "No results matched xy"). How do I have to do that?